# ner, spacy,sentence segmentation

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to break this sentences in order to process it using spacy

```
Finally, on 1595 July 22 at 2h 40m am, when the sun was at 7° 59' 52" Leo, 101,487 distant from earth, Mars's mean longitude 11s 14° 9' 5", and anomaly 164° 48' 55", and consequent eccentric position from the vicarious hypothesis 17° 16' 36" Pisces: the apparent position of Mars, from the most select observations, was 4° 11' 10" Taurus, lat. 2° 30' S ^37. Thus we twice have Mars in the most opportune position, in quadrature with the sun, while the positions of earth and Mars are also distant by a quadrant.\n
```

I want to result be like this :

```
[
Finally, on 1595 July 22 at 2h 40m am, when the sun was at 7° 59' 52" Leo, 101,487 distant from earth, Mars's mean longitude 11s 14° 9' 5", and anomaly 164° 48' 55", and consequent eccentric position from the vicarious hypothesis 17° 16' 36" Pisces: the apparent position of Mars, from the most select observations, was 4° 11' 10" Taurus, lat. 2° 30' S ^37. ,

  Thus we twice have Mars in the most opportune position, in quadrature with the sun, while the positions of earth and Mars are also distant by a quadrant.\n ]
```

It means two sentences, the first one should finish after lat. 2° 30' S ^37. but since lat. has a dote , it breaks the sentences after lat.

but I did not find the solution till now I have used these 2 approaches:

```
def set_custom_boundaries(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text in ("lat."):
            # print("Detected:", token.text)
            doc[token.i].is_sent_start = False
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(set_custom_boundaries, before="parser")
nlp.pipeline
```

and

```
a.split('.')
```

I  think some small mistakes in the first code.

both above methods do not work to split the sentences as desired!

generally, what do you recommend in order to segment paragraph to sentences? (especially when we have) such abbreviation cases lie

```
lat.
```

Comment: _It means two sentences, the first one finish after lat. 2° 30' S ^37._ Can you share the text in a better/clearer format? _both do not work!_ What does that mean? _generally, what do you recommend in order to segment paragraph to sentences?_ Use a library designed to work with natural language, which you're already doing.

Comment: I have edited the texts. basically the question is the word like  " lat." which is abbreviation cause to break of  the sentences which are not desired, what would be your approach to segment the paragraph to correct sentences

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and it works

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
def SentenceSegmentation(Para):
        punkt_param = PunktParameters()
        abbreviation = ['lat', 'ch']  #any abbrivation  lat-> latitiude  ch--> chapter
        punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(abbreviation)
        tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
        tokenizer.train(Para)
        return tokenizer.tokenize(Para)
```